# Third party dll added in visual studio: are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I created once a `Tester.dll` file with visual studio that I now want to use for a new visual studio project. In the solution explorer I clicked on the project and added the `dll`, which I can then see under the assemblies. Then in the `Program.cs` file I wrote `using Tester;`.

If I build it I get the error message `The type or namespace Tester could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)`

Is there another step I have missed ?

My project structure looks as follows:

```
Server
│ └── Communication.sln
|── Lib
│ ├── Tester.dll
├── CommunicationServer
│ ├── bin
│ ├── obj
│ ├── CommunicationServer.csproj
│ └── Program.cs
│ ├── Tester.dll
├── Communication
│ ├── bin
│ ├── obj
│ ├── Communication.csproj
```

Unfortunately I don't really know either visual studio or C #.

Comment: You need to add a reference to Tester.dll in CommunicationServer (under Dependencies) - you should not be adding the dll to the project directly.

Comment: If I give a reference to `Tester.dll` (in the folder where it really was produced) It still can not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your project in visual studio then go to solution explorer window. There you will see a section as references, right click on references, select add reference option from the menu. A window will appear, at bottom there's an option to browse, now locate the Tester.dll, build the application. Your code should now compile successfully.

**Note: Class which you are trying to access from Tester.dll should be marked with public access modifier.**